# flutter library not connected

Tags: flutter, dart

help me figure out what should I do?

LibraryHelper: Library package:flutter/src/widgets/widget_inspector.dart is not loaded. This can happen for unreferenced libraries.

I tried to import this library into the project, but it did not help

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.